# Why do I get an error code when importing pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to learn pyqt5, so I am trying to write a simple program.

The problem is that I get an error message after running my code

I import the following:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
```

and get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/DATA/DOCUMENTS/GAS PROJECT/gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

I installed pyqt5 with pip and also after getting the error messages I installed it with homebrew.

If I use Python default idle or PyCharm, my code runs ok, the problem is with VS Code (I tried to use the different path available for Python in the right bottom corner of vs code without better results).

Any help, please?

Comment: It sounds like you're using two different interpreters. Have you tried to choose the same interpreter in vs code as your PyCharm?

Comment: yes, pycharm uses /usr/local/bin/python3.11.

I tried this in vs code and also the other 2 available options:

/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 and /usr/bin/python3